# Redirect to specific paypal sale site from php?

Tags: php, paypal

Hello i have a form on my site so far so good

The Problem begins here my user after submitting/processing the form he land to the site where the specific paypal button is placed.

But here comes the interesting part i want to redirect my user after clicking on my pay now button to the specific paypal page using my custom.php script this mean i want to include this code;

```
<?php

session_start(); 
$_SESSION['form_finished'] = true; 
header('Location: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr'); 

?>
```

Why this ? because i want that after my user finish the payment procedure to be able to redirected to my thank you page where i have this on top :

```
 <?php
session_start();
if(!$_SESSION['form_finished']) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    exit;
}
?>
```

As you can see i want only users that click the pay now button to be able to see my thank you page.
Any help will greatly be welcomed , thanks

Comment: Which Paypal API are you using? Most of the PayPal services require the return url anyway..

Comment: It looks like things on your end are fine, you just need to wire up the paypal API calls to specify that return url.

Comment: Redirecting to PayPal like that won't work. PayPal WPS needs the payment information to be POSTed, so you must use a form to send the payment info to PayPal. In that form, you need to add the `return` variable with a URL so PayPal can redirect customers to that URL after payment. More about it here: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside